# Can I list the files and directories on a logical volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ls

I have a logical volume, /dev/dm-0, 95% full. I want to delete some directories and files from it to free up space. 
I have no idea how to list what files and dirs are on it. Google doesn't even have an answer it seems. I have to believe this is possible, but crazy how hard it is to find the answer.

Comment: Since this isn't really a programming question, you may find better luck on unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com (both stackexchage sites, but more relevant).

Comment: Yes, this would be on-topic at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), but could use some clarifying. To start, have you already mounted the volume?

Comment: Yep @wjandrea, it is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the directory and execute b
find . -type f